# Regex must contain specific letters in any order

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have been attempting to validate a string in VB.net that must contain these three letters in no particular order and do not need to be next to One another. ABC

I can do this easily using LINQ

```
MessageBox.Show(("ABC").All(Function(n) ("AAAABBBBBCCCC").Contains(n)).ToString)
```

However, after searching Google and SO for over a week, I am completely stumped. My closest pattern is `".*[A|B|C]+.*[A|B|C]+.*[A|B|C]+.*"` how ever `AAA` would also return true. I know i can do this using other methods just after trying for a week i really want to know if its possible using One regular expression.

Comment: Is there a reason you need Regex? And is it always just a set of 3 characters?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use regex. In order to learn One must set tasks for his/her self. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: You might try a different problem for learning regex. While it's possible to solve this one, as Jerry has shown, it's not a particularly good problem for a regular expression (many string libraries even offer a `ContainsAll` method).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your original pattern won't work because it will match any number of characters, followed by one or more `A`, `B`, `C`, or `|` character, followed by any number of characters, followed by one or more `A`, `B`, `C`, or `|` character, followed by any number of characters, followed by one or more `A`, `B`, `C`, or `|` character, followed by any number of characters.

I'd probably go with the code you've already written, but if you really want to use a regular expression, you can use a series of [lookahead assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion), like this:

```
(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)
```

This will match any string that contains `A`, `B`, and `C` in any order.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain my pattern and providing an example.

Comment: You should mention the lookaheads are zero-width matches and should be followed by a pattern to match against (eg a `.+` following the lookaheads): `(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C).+`

Comment: @bobobobo Not necessarily. A zero-length string is a valid pattern, so if you're just testing for a match (and you don't care to actually capture a match), then just having a zero-width assertion alone works fine. See https://repl.it/repls/BumpyFoolhardyBarnswallow

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of positive lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C).+
```

`(?=.*A)` makes sure there's an A somewhere in the string and the same logic applies to the other lookaheads.

Comment: Oh my. How close i was not. I understand the grouping but would you mind explaining (?= Is that the positive look a head?

Comment: @SamJohnson Yup! It's a bit of an 'advanced' regex syntax if you ask me. I took a while myself to understand them as I do now. Basically, you will get a match only if the condition within the brackets is matched. So, if the string matches `.*A` (i.e. any character, then an `A`, it will match). Applying 3 like that in a row is like checking 3 conditions and making sure they are satisfied before continuing further. This is a rough description of the lookahead, but you can get more information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you for much for your time and effort. I accepted your answer. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @SamJohnson Unfortunately you can 'accept' only one answer, that's how the site works ^^; But it's okay if you accept p.s.w.g's answer. I should probably have mentioned why your regex was not working as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **zero-width lookaheads**. Lookaheads are great to eliminate match possibilities if they don't meet a certain criteria.

For example, let's use the words

```
untie queue unique block unity
```

Start with a basic word match:

```
\b\w+\b
```

to require the word matched with `\w+` begins with `un`, we could use a ***positive lookahead***

```
\b(?=un)\w+\b
```

What this says is

- `\b` Match a blank
- `(?=un)` Are there the letters "un"? If not, NO MATCH. If so, then possible match.
- `\w+` One or more word characters
- `\b` Match a blank

A positive lookahead eliminates a match possibility if it does NOT meet the expression inside. It applies to the regex RIGHT AFTER it. So the `(?=un)` applies to the `\w+` expression above and requires that it BEGINS WITH `un`. If it does not, then the `\w+` expression won't match.

How about matching any words that **do not** begin with `un`?  Simply use a "negative lookahead"

```
\b(?!un)\w+\b
```

- `\b` Match a blank
- `(?!un)` Are there the letters "un"? If ***SO***, NO MATCH. If not, then possible match.
- `\w+` One or more word characters
- `\b` Match a blank

So for your requirement of having at least 1 A, 1 B and 1 C in the string, a pattern like

```
(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C).+
```

Works because it says:

- `(?=.*A)` - Does it have `.*` any characters followed by A? If so, possible match if not no match.
- `(?=.*B)` - Does it have `.*` any characters followed by B? If so, possible match if not no match.
- `(?=.*C)` - Does it have `.*` any characters followed by C? If so, possible match if not no match.
- `.+` If the above 3 lookahead requirements were met, **match any characters**. If not, then match no characters (and so there isn't a match)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a regex? That's something that can easily be solved without one.

I've never programmed in VB, but I'm sure there are helper functions that let you take a string, and query whether or not a character occurs in it.

If str is your string, maybe something like:

str.contains('A') && str.contains('B') && str.contains('C')

Comment: "Does it have to be a regex? That's something that can easily be solved without one." 

Didn't i already not provide a working example not using regex?